# Assigning value to pandas column not working

Tags: python, pandas

I'm checking if a dataframe is empty and then assigning a value if it is. Dataframe has columns "NAME" and "ROLE"

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['NAME', 'ROLE'])

if df.empty:
    df["NAME"] = "Jake"
```

After assigning "Jake" to "NAME". The dataframe is still empty like so:

| NAME | ROLE |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |

but I want the dataframe to look like this:

| NAME | ROLE |
| --- | --- |
| Jake |  |

Comment: Are you sure `df.empty` is true?

Comment: Since the dataframe is empty, you assign 0 "Jake"'s to the empty column. I'm not sure what your `|NAME|ROLE| |:---|:---:| | | |` thing is... that's why examples matter! ... but if `df` isn't empty, than the if doesn't run and nothing gets assigned.

Comment: How many rows should the resulting dataframe have? You could do `df["NAME"] = ["Jake"]` to make one row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assigning a scalar to a pandas dataframe sets each value in that column to the scalar. Since you have zero rows, `df["NAME"] = "Jake"` doesn't assign anything. If you assign a list however, the dataframe is extended for that list. To get a single row in the dataframe

```
df["NAME"] = ["Jake"]
```

You could create more rows by adding additional values to the list being assigned.

Answer (score 1):

As people are saying in the comments, there are no rows in your empty dataframe to assign the value "Jake" to the "Name" column. Showing that in the first example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name','Role'])
df['Name'] = 'Jake'
print(df)
```

I'm guessing instead you want to add a row:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name','Role'])
df = df.append({'Name':'Jake','Role':None},ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change more than one row value you can use .loc method in Pandas module:

change_index = data_["sample_column"].sample(150).index # index of rows whose value will change

data_["sample_column"].loc[sample_index] = 1 # value at specified index and specified column is changed or assigned to 1

Note : If you write as data_.loc[sample_index]["sample_column"]. = 1 it is not working! Because ["sample_column"] condition write as before .loc methods.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).